# Thinking outside of the box

Tags: geometry, soft-question, circles, geometric-construction

You want to draw a circle with a 4 inch radius.  A trivial task for you and your trusty compass.  When you go to grab your compass which has not had much love for a while you find it is rusted shut; stuck at 5 inches.  Is it still possible to complete the task and draw a perfect circle with a 4-inch radius using the compass that can only draw circles with a 5-inch radius?

You may use other things as well to solve the problem such as a straightedge.

Comment: you can if you have infinite time you can construct a segment of  4 inch distance, but not draw a circle of 4 inch so draw a circle of 5 inch and then in every direction draw a segment of four

Comment: No, you already answered the question for yourself. If it could draw a circle with a 4-inch radius, then it would not be a compass "that can only draw circles with a 5-inch radius", would it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### My first approach

Yes, just place the center 3 inches above the paper. If that is a possibility?

### Different rendering

To put it differently, if you like, you could draw a 5-inch-circle, use scissors to cut a radius, then form a cone by overlapping at the cutting line until the proportion of the height to the radius of the base is 3 to 4...

That will happen when the overlap covers $\frac{1}{4}$ of the surface of the cone...

### Illustrations

To fully earn your votes, here is an illustration:

[image]

To see the situation from arbitrary angles, consult the following dynamic 3D-graph:

[GeoGebra-illustration](http://www.geogebratube.org/material/show/id/83444)

In particular, see what it looks like from above - the $1:4$ proportion of the overlap becomes evident!

Comment: Yes that is one solution.  You can use a 3 inch block to raise the center.

Comment: I think the initial one-line solution was perfect because it was also practical. IMHO, no need to add anything...

Comment: @Vadim: You are quite right, although my last edit suggests a way to measure the exact result by eye, if I am not mistaken :)

Comment: Very nice.  Yes I agree the first answer wins in practicality, but the second is more imaginative.  I asked this question to open a talk I gave and the only answer I got was WD-40.

Comment: @DavidCaliri: I added an illustration of the cone-solution. Be sure to visit the link adress to see the dynamic version of it!

Comment: And just at a suggestion to anyone who takes interest in the dynamic 3D-version given in the link: feel free to download GeoGebra (it is free) for yourselves and download the document - then the rendering will run smoothly without delays and lacking in performance.

Answer (score 0):

Lay a ruler along one side of the compass with zero mark adjacent to the axis of the compass. set a pencil at the 4 inch mark of the ruler and maintain it there as you rotate the compass and ruler as a unit, completing a full rotation.